# how to make a .text file in terminal python3.33

Tags: python

I was wondering how to make a .text file so I can put words in it and then in my program open the file. I just need to know how to make a .text file!

Anyone know why my code won't open my .txt file when I try to run it?

```
def readWords(filename):
    words = []
    wordFile = open(words.txt, "r")
    for line in wordFile:
        line = line.upper()
        words.extend(string.split(line))
    wordFile.close()
    return words
```

Comment: Don't edit new/different issues into your old post, because it destroys the context of existing answers on your question.  You should create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file in write mode will create it for you if it doesn't already exist:

```
with open("/path/to/file.txt", "w") as myfile:
    # Do whatever
```

In the above code, `myfile` will be the file object.

Here is a reference on [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) and one on [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('potato')
```